# Squeeze all but one axis in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

How can I squeeze all but specific axis(es) of a `Tensor`?

The input size (and how many `1` dimension there is) is unknown in advance but I know that I wanna keep the first and second axis only (i.e. the rest can be only 1).

e.g. If I have a `Tensor` of shape `(1, 4, 1, 1, 1)` and I want it to be squeezed into `(1, 4)`

Comment: Wouldn't `tf.reshape(tf.squeeze(t), [1, -1])` work? Here `t` is your tensor.

Comment: No need to squeeze actually if the other axes are always 1; you can reshape directly.